# Ionic 5: Is there a way to combine tabs and side menu

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I wanto to use both styles `<ion-tabs></ion-tabs>` and `<ion-menu></<ion-menu>` for some reason when I activate them both, the side menu disapear, I tried to make my tabs into a component but i get the same result, any idea of how to do it? and i dont want that the tabs shows in specific pages, i want them in the entire app

```html
<ion-split-pane>
    <ion-menu contentId="content">
        <ion-header>
            <ion-toolbar>
                <ion-title>Menú</ion-title>
            </ion-toolbar>
        </ion-header>
        <ion-content>
            <ion-list>
                <ion-menu-toggle auto-hide="false" *ngFor="let p of appPages">
                    <ion-item [routerLink]="p.url" routerDirection="forward"
                              [class.active-item]="selectedPath === p.url">
                        <ion-icon name="{{p.icon}}" slot="start"></ion-icon>
                        {{p.title}}
                    </ion-item>

                </ion-menu-toggle>
                <ion-item tappable="" (click)="logoutAction()">
                    <ion-icon name="log-out" slot="start"></ion-icon>
                    Salir
                </ion-item>
            </ion-list>

        </ion-content>
    </ion-menu>
    <ion-router-outlet id="content" main></ion-router-outlet>

</ion-split-pane>

<ion-tabs>
<ion-tab-bar slot="bottom" color="dark">
    <ion-tab-button tab="feed">
        <ion-icon name="paper"></ion-icon>
        <ion-label>Feed</ion-label>
    </ion-tab-button>

    <ion-tab-button tab="messages">
        <ion-icon name="send"></ion-icon>
        <ion-label>Messages</ion-label>
    </ion-tab-button>

    <ion-tab-button tab="notifications">
        <ion-icon name="notifications"></ion-icon>
        <ion-label>Contact</ion-label>
    </ion-tab-button>

    <ion-tab-button tab="settings">
        <ion-icon name="cog"></ion-icon>
        <ion-label>Settings</ion-label>
    </ion-tab-button>

</ion-tab-bar>
```

Comment: Follow this link https://meumobi.github.io/ionic/2018/11/13/side-menu-tabs-login-page-ionic4.html

Comment: I am using both the side menu and tabs in my Ionic / Stencil app, which is live here: https://codyburleson.com . I don't have time right now to provide an answer, but perhaps if you look at my implementation code, you might get some ideas from it that will help. The code is on GitHub here: https://github.com/codyburleson/cburleson-pwa . I think you should look at app-root.tsx and app-tabs.tsx to start with.

Answer (score 12):

I know i am very late to answer but it may help future users. I wanted to combine sidemenu and tabs style. So i did it in Following way. (I am using new project for this example)

1. Download new ionic 5 tabs project using following cli command

> ionic start myApp tabs --capacitor

Run the project using `ionic serve` to check project is running properly.

Now we have project with tabs style and we want to add side-menu in it.
So lets Create new page named as ' inbox ' using ionic cli command: `ionic g page inbox`.

`app-routing.module.ts` file will look like this

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { PreloadAllModules, RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    loadChildren: () => import('./tabs/tabs.module').then(m => m.TabsPageModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'inbox',
    loadChildren: () => import('./inbox/inbox.module').then( m => m.InboxPageModule)
  }


];
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules })
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

Okay now we just have to add this inbox page in side menu. to do this

2.Go to `app.component.html` and add the following code in it (Remove old code)

> 

```
<ion-app>
    <ion-split-pane contentId="main-content">
        <ion-menu contentId="main-content" type="overlay">
            <ion-content>
                <ion-list id="inbox-list">
                    <ion-list-header>Side Menu</ion-list-header>
                    <ion-menu-toggle auto-hide="false" *ngFor="let p of appPages; let i = index">
                        <ion-item (click)="selectedIndex = i" routerDirection="root" [routerLink]="[p.url]" lines="none"
                                  detail="false" [class.selected]="selectedIndex == i">
                            <ion-icon slot="start" [ios]="p.icon + '-outline'" [md]="p.icon + '-sharp'"></ion-icon>
                            <ion-label>{{ p.title }}</ion-label>
                        </ion-item>
                    </ion-menu-toggle>
                </ion-list>
            </ion-content>
        </ion-menu>
        <ion-router-outlet id="main-content"></ion-router-outlet>
    </ion-split-pane>
</ion-app>
```

3.Go to `app.component.ts` your app.component.ts file should look like this.

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import { Plugins } from '@capacitor/core';
const { SplashScreen } = Plugins;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: 'app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit{
  public selectedIndex = 0;
  public appPages = [
    {
      title: 'Home',
      url: '/tabs',
      icon: 'home'
    },
    {
      title: 'Inbox',
      url: '/inbox',
      icon: 'mail'
    }
  ];
  constructor() {
    this.initializeApp();
  }

  initializeApp() {
    SplashScreen.hide();
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    const path = window.location.pathname.split('/')[1];
    console.log(path)
    if (path !== undefined) {
      this.selectedIndex = this.appPages.findIndex(page => page.title.toLowerCase() === path.toLowerCase());
    }
  }
}
```

4.Go to `app.component.scss`  add following style

```
   ion-item.selected {
  --color: var(--ion-color-primary);
}
```

5.Now last step go to the pages in which you want to add side menu and add side menu code in header section.
Example:

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-buttons slot="start">
      <ion-menu-button></ion-menu-button>
    </ion-buttons>
    <ion-title>
      Your Page Title
    </ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>
```

[In our case for this example we will add above code in `inbox.page.html tab1.page.html tab2.page.html tab3.page.html`]

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

other answer is correct, and use explicit and multiple ion router outlet (ion tab use implicit outlet).

but Ion documentation suggest

> When not using a router, contentId is typically
> your main view's `ion-content`. contentId is not the
> id of the `ion-content` inside of your `ion-menu`.

add a id attr on your parent ion-content tag, and provide same id on ion-menu as contentId, it should work fine.

```
<ion-content id="main">...</ion-content>

<ion-menu contentId="main">...</ion-menu>
```

refer [line 76 of components/menu/menu.tsx](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-framework/blob/2af24494f528e029d00bf208e7ec4d8f2461b263/core/src/components/menu/menu.tsx#L76)
[image]